# How to sort a string array in ascending order according to a particular unit?

Tags: java, string, sorting

```
String[] stringArray = {"1 kbps", "100 bps", "10 mbps", "2 gbps"};
```

the needed output

`{ "100 bps","1 kbps", "10 mbps", "2 gbps"}`

in ascending order

Comment: Writing your own [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html) may be best. Then you can just pass an instance of it to `Arrays.sort()`.

Comment: Deserialize those values, in other words parse those strings into a more useful format. `"1 kbps"` is a nice human-readable value, but the integer `1000` (or is it `1024`?) is much more useful when you need to handle it in any way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use comparator like this:

> ```
> String[] stringArray = {"1 kbps", "100 bps", "10 mbps", "2 gbps"};
> Arrays.sort(stringArray, new SpeedComparator());
> System.out.println(Arrays.asList(stringArray));
> // [100 bps, 1 kbps, 10 mbps, 2 gbps]
> ```

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class SpeedComparator implements Comparator<String> {

  public int compare(String o1, String o2) {

    int indexSeparator1 = o1.indexOf(' ');
    int indexSeparator2 = o2.indexOf(' ');
    String number1 = o1.substring(0, indexSeparator1);
    String number2 = o2.substring(0, indexSeparator2);

    double value1 = Double.valueOf(number1);
    double value2 = Double.valueOf(number2);

    String measure1 = o1.substring(indexSeparator1 + 1, o1.length());
    String measure2 = o2.substring(indexSeparator2 + 1, o2.length());

    value1 = getRealValue(value1, measure1);
    value2 = getRealValue(value2, measure2);

    return (int) (value1 - value2);

  }

  private double getRealValue(double value, String measure) {
    switch (Measure.valueOf(measure.toUpperCase())) {
      case BPS:
        return value;
      case KBPS:
        return value * 1000;
      case MBPS:
        return value * 1000000;
      case GBPS:
        return value * 1000000000;
    }
    return value;
  }

  enum Measure {
    BPS, KBPS, MBPS, GBPS
  }
}
```